# Capturing the first video frame

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I found many article in stackoverflow talking about how to capture the first video image frame, but I don't see what I'm doing wrong on the code to make it not working. So if someone can help me, thanks a lot !

HTML code:

```
<ion-button expand="block" color="primary" (click)="onPickVideo()">
   <ion-icon name="videocam" slot="start"></ion-icon>
   <ion-label>Select video</ion-label>
 </ion-button>

  <input type="file" (change)="onFileChosen($event)" #filePicker/>

<div class="wrapper" *ngIf="flag">
  <video controls >
    <source [src]="videoDetail.dataString" type="video/mp4">
    unsupported video
  </video>
</div>
```

TS Code:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

export interface VideoDetail {
  ... Some code ...
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  ... Some code ...

  onPickVideo() {
    this.filePickerRef.nativeElement.click();
  }


  onFileChosen(ev: Event) {
    const files: FileList = (ev.target as HTMLInputElement).files;

  ... Some code ...      

    this.videoMetadataReader(this.videoBuffer, this.videoDetail);

    this.convertToDataString(this.videoBuffer, this.videoDetail);
  }

  // Metadata video reader
  videoMetadataReader(buffer: File, detail: VideoDetail) {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    this.videoBuffer = files[0];   // get video file

    fileReader.onload = () => {
      const blob = new Blob([fileReader.result], {type});

      const url = (URL || webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
      const video = document.createElement('video');  // create video element

      video.preload = 'metadata';                     // preload setting
      video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {

       ... Some code ...

        // Get first frame
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        const img = new Image();


        canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
        canvas.width = video.videoWidth;

        ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);


        img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
        detail.videoFrame = img.src;

        console.log('img :', img.src);

      });
      video.src = url; // start video load
    };
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(buffer);
  }

  // File to dataUrl
  convertToDataString(buffer: File, detail: VideoDetail) {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = () => {
      const dataString = fileReader.result.toString();
      detail.dataString = dataString;
      this.flag = true;
    };
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(buffer);
  }
}
```

When I see the img in console.log I get an image, but totally white, and it should not be white.

**Edit to show screenshot:**  In red the video frame capture, white.

[image]

Thanks again for help :)

**Edited to add app link download :**

[Download source code here](https://github.com/jbdioli/Video.git)

Comment: Are you sure that your device actually supports video encoding format?

Comment: well it's on chrome

Comment: It looks the video is not fully loaded. So I just get a part of the frame. Someone know how can I know the video is fully loaded ?

Comment: [`loadeddata`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#Events) looks like the correct event: "The first frame of the media has finished loading."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reproduced your problem: you should replace preload type from `preload` to `auto` and event `loadedmetadata` should be changed to `loadeddata` or `canplay`.

BTW, I've used function below to convert blob to dataUri (can be changed to async or promises):

```
function blobToDataURL(blob, callback) {
  var a = new FileReader();
  a.onload = function(e) {callback(e.target.result);}
  a.readAsDataURL(blob);
}
```

Comment: I get an error message when I change preload to auto.     `error TS2339: Property 'auto' does not exist on type 'HTMLVideoElement'.`

Comment: I've edit the question to add the link of the code for download

Comment: I got what you said ! `video.preload = 'auto';` and `video.addEventListener('loadeddata', () => {`

Comment: I've updated the github link with the correction. You can download to working code. @stck Thanks!